# How to suppress a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have this data frame:

```
                      age     Income   Job yrs
Churn Own Home                                
0     0         39.497576  42.540247  7.293301
      1         42.667392  58.975215  8.346974
1     0         44.499774  45.054619  7.806146
      1         47.615546  60.187945  8.525210
```

Born from this line of code:

```
gb = df3.groupby(['Churn', 'Own Home'])['age', 'Income', 'Job yrs'].mean()
```

I want to "suppress" or unstack this data frame so that it looks like this:

```
    Churn  Own Home   age    Income   Job yrs    
0  0       0          39.49  42.54    7.29
1  0       1          42.66  58.97    8.34
2  1       0          44.49  45.05    7.80
3  1       1          47.87  60.18    8.52
```

I have tried using both .stack() and .unstack() with no luck, also I was not able to find anything online talking about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataFrame looks like a MultiIndex that you can revert to a single index using the command :

```
gb.reset_index(level=[0,1])
```